# Multiple table inner join need first table id

Tags: php, mysql

Working that query. Than i need projects table's id. `echo $row['id']` is printing `users->id`. But i need print projects->id.

```
SELECT * FROM projects INNER JOIN users ON projects.manager = users.id
```

Comment: there are 2 same fields so you should use as to differentiate them, `SELECT p.*,users.id as user_id FROM projects p INNER JOIN users ON projects.manager = user_id`

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create alias like below:

```
SELECT *, projects.id as prodict_id, users.id as user_id FROM projects INNER JOIN users ON projects.manager = users.id
```

then you can use it

```
$row['prodict_id']
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)